# How to add a private (in header) property on a category?

Tags: ios, objective-c, categories

I have in my header:

```
@interface UIImageView (MyImageView)
```

Then in my source I would like to add a few private properties, so I do:

```
@interface UIImageView (MyImageView)
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL isBlah;
@end
```

But I get a `Duplicate definition of category 'MyImageView' on interface 'UIImageView'` on the header file line (see above).

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating two instances of the same category. Name your second something else (instead of `MyImageView`), or better yet just use a class extension there:

```
@interface UIImageView ()
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL isBlah;
@end
```

(Though it's strange that a class extension works here; it actually shouldn't since we don't have the source to `UIImageView`. But it does in iOS 8… This may be a compiler bug or a new feature. Normally you'd make this a named category rather than an extension as rmaddy notes below.)

Comment: 1) Can you create a class extension on `UIImageView` (or other existing classes you didn't write)? 2) If you can add a class extension to a class you didn't write, you still can't add an ivar to the category (since you can't compile the base implementation), so the property can't be backed by a synthesized ivar.

Comment: @meaning-matters You can't add ivars through a category. You can add properties, but they can't be backed by an ivar. There are a few options to get around that limitation. Though most likely you would be better off creating a subclass instead of a category depending on how the property is used.

Comment: @rmaddy 1) You should be right, but in fact it works (and I keep trying to figure out if iOS 8 just automatically converts it to a category, or if this is a bug in iOS 8). But yeah, in general you should name it rather than making it a class extension; I wasn't focusing on the fact that it was `UIImageView`. 2) It's true that it can't be backed by a synthesized ivar. That has nothing to do with whether you can declare the property. As long as you implement the required accessors, everything is fine.

Comment: @meaning-matters, it's up to you to come up with some way to store and retrieve this value. There won't be an ivar for you and it can't synthesize the accessors. If you really need storage, the most common solution is associated objects.

Comment: @maddy and Rob Thanks for the great suggestions & insight. (I Like your books Rob!)  I read about [associated objects](http://kingscocoa.com/tutorials/associated-objects/) (which is good to keep in mind), but ended up creating a subclass in this case.